# How do I execute javascript only relative to that frame and not the whole window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have the following iFrame:

```
<div id="sandbox-inner">
    <iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts" frameborder="0" name="Output " id="output" src="JavaScript:''"></iframe>
</div>
```

And when the user clicks to run their code, it injects the javascript successfully within this iframe. However, it actually runs it across the whole window, not just the iframe. So basically if I add a class "test" to an element outside the iframe, and one inside, and then inject the following inside the head of the iframe...

```
$(function() {
      $('.test').css({ background: "blue" });
});
```

It effects my element outside the iframe too, which I really dont want. I need the iFrame to be a completely seperate environment. This is how I am currently injecting the javascript:

```
$('#runGuestCode').on("click", function () {

        var js = $('#js-input').val(),           
            iframe = $("#output"),
            iframeHead = iframe.contents().find("head").first(),
            frame = document.getElementById("output"),
            scriptTag = '<script>' + js + '<\/script>';

        $('#output').contents().find("head").append(scriptTag);
    });
```

Many thanks

UPDATE #1

The javascript is taken from textarea #js-input, which is whatever the user has typed. This is then appended to the head of the iframe, but currently runs relative to the parent document, not the iframe document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it following way, it will not effect you current page elements will apply to iframe element only:-

```
var iframe = $('iframe');
$(element,  iframe.contents()).css({'background':'blue'});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5t44wvdh/7/)**

Showcase the javascript code put by user in iframe:

```
$('#submit1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myIframe = document.getElementById("resultFrame");
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.innerHTML = $("#textarea1").val();
    myIframe.contentWindow.document.head.appendChild(s);
});
```

**[Working Fiddle with Javascript Output in iframe](http://jsfiddle.net/5t44wvdh/18/)**

Comment: thanks for your example, but I need it to work for any and all css applied. So this works for one element, but what about adding classes which are on multiple elements.

Comment: Are you adding the classes using javascript? if so then just add in every selector `,iframe.contents()` which select the element of iframe. Please elaborate what you actually want to do>

Comment: ok, so I have a textarea (id = "js-input" ) and I grab the contents of this which is user defined (anything) and dynamically add it to the iframe head, which then runs the javascript upon adding. The issue is it seems to run for the whole window, not just the iframe

Comment: So you want to take the value from textarea of main document put it in the head of iframe and then apply js.So What kind of js function you want to apply as almost everything can be done by main document if you apply the js in main document then append it  iframe. It would better if shared what kind of script you are applying.

Comment: whatever the user types. think of the tryit editor in w3 schools. u type js in their window, and they send it through to the iframe and whatever js u write only effects the iframe and not the whole window

Comment: Update my answer, after reading your question I got a little confused about what do you want to do. Thanks for your clear explanation. This deals the iframe as separate environment which is what you wanted in your question.

Comment: if I could upvote twice I would, since you also got jQuery going in there :D many thanks